# Requesting Sensor.TYPE_HEART_BEAT returns null in Android 9 Ticwatch c2

Tags: android, google-fit, heartbeat

I would like to use `Sensor.TYPE_HEART_BEAT` from **Androids Sensor API** to measure heart rate variability, however when requested from my application it returns null.

I've checked my manifest permissions for `BODY_SENSORS` which has no effect. `Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE` also seems to be working fine.

```
    Sensor sensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_BEAT);

    if (sensor == null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Sensor is null");
    }
```

I would expect this to return a valid sensor but it returns null.  I am using the Ticwatch c2 which does have a heart rate sensor.  I'm not sure why heart beat is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://forum.mobvoi.com/viewtopic.php?t=53684) on the mobvoi community forms, the Ticwatch C2 does not have a heart beat sensor.

The post also recommends using the adb command `adb shell dumpsys sensorservice` to list all available sensors for any watch.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I forgot to update the post.  When I contacted Mobvoi myself I got a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, from SDK 23 and onward  you have to ask for permissions separately on the wear device and the phone. The Wear app no longer inherits permissions from the phone app.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem, I'm currently contacting Mobvoi to see if its a manufacturer issue.  This wouldn't be the first time I've had a manufacturer incorrectly configure the sensors on their wear device.